# Should we say "The shop sold flowers" or "The shop was selling flowers" to talk about what goods a shop provides to people?

Tags: tense

In the present tense, we say "The shop sells flowers", but my search on the internet shows the sentence "The shop was sellling X" is more common and "The shop sold X" seems to be referring to a single instance of selling something, but then again, if "The shop was selling X" is more natural, how come we can't say "The shop is selling X" in the present tense and instead we say "The shop sells X"?

Also, are both of these sentences correct?

> The street child sold me a flower.

> The street child sold a flower to me.

If we bought only a single flower and not a bunch of flowers.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between simple past and past continuous? That's what those tenses mean here

Answer (score 1):

"The shop sold flowers" would be a correct and natural way to speak of a shop that has stopped selling flowers completely.

> Eliza and Fred ran a shop that sold flowers.  The shop is still there, but it has been converted into a cafe.

However, it may be more common to speak of past activity, without implying if the shop has closed or not

> I passed a shop selling flowers, so a bought a bunch for my husband.

But if you want to talk "about what goods a shop *provides* to people", you'd use a present tense.

Both "sell me X" and "sell X to me" are correct, though the first is slightly shorter and may be prefered.

Comment: Thanks a lot, James. So to sum it up. I should say: "I went to the shopping center. The shops were selling all kinds of things." and if I'm talking about the present, I should say "The shops sell X" rather than "The shops are selling X" . Also, if the shop has stopped selling something, we can say "The shop sold X" or "The shop used to sell X". Did I get it all right?

Comment: Yes, those all look like good English.

Comment: I don't consider that _The shop sold flowers_ is limited to businesses that have ceased trading. "I walked past a shop that sold flowers" (it was  a florist's shop). "I walked past a shop that was selling tulips" (it had a display of tulips on that particular day).

Comment: I don't think it needs to have ceased trading.  Only ceased selling flowers.  "My local supermarket sold flowers until last year. Now it only sells food."